# Refer to method in module with same name as class

Tags: ruby

I have a class and a module which have the same names:

```rb
module Pushover
  def configure
    ..
  end
end

module MyModule
  class Pushover
    def blah
      Pushover.configure
    end
  end
end
```

This doesn't work because the `Pushover.configure` call directs to the containing class. Now, an obvious fix would be to rename the class. However, the Module is from a gem and the class conforms to a naming convention required in a DSL. So ideally they should both stay the same. I could also create a second helper class and call via that, but that all seems a little hacky. My preferred solution would be to directly reference the module method.

All the existing questions around this area seem to be disambiguating in the opposite direction - i.e. they want to get the class reference not the module.

Is there any way for me to inform Ruby that I mean the module rather than the class when I specify `Pushover`?

Comment: Why do you have to name the module `Pushover` and the `Pushover` class in another module the same thing? That seems like you're asking for trouble, especially over the long-term if you have to get into debugging or maintenance.

Comment: I agree. However, I don't have a great deal of choice. I'm providing a patch to someone else's application using someone else's gem. If I change the class name to be MyModule::PushoverNotifier, then "DSL" which uses this will look odd. (This is for the Backup gem btw.). User's currently can do `notify_by Twitter` or `notify_by Mail`. So `notify by Pushover` seems a logical extension, rather than `notify_by PushoverNotifier`, which would be an exception to the standard.

Comment: Ugh. That's when maintaining code gets ugly, when you're backed into a corner because of someone else's choices. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't want to look up the constant relative to the current scope, just use an absolute path:

```
::Pushover.configure
```

Comment: Ah! So the :: effectively escapes you from the current scope. I didn't fully appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: It works exactly like the `/` in filesystem paths. Paths that start with `/` are absolute (or are relative to the root directory), others are relative. In Ruby, constant lookup starts at the current scope, whereas `::` starts at the "global scope" (actually, there is no global scope, it starts at the `Object` class).